# The input does not contain any JSON tokens. Expected the input to start with a valid JSON token on LIVE Web API but works fine locally

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi

I have this very odd issue I detail here:
https://github.com/NextGenSoftwareUK/Our-World-OASIS-API-HoloNET-HoloUnity-And-.NET-HDK/issues/14

Which I have copied below:

URI: http://oasisplatform.world/api/avatar/authenticate
Post Body Data:
{
"email": "davidellams@hotmail.com",
"password": "my-super-secret-password"
}

Use Postman or something similar to send the above and you will get back this:

{"type":"https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1","title":"One or more validation errors occurred.","status":400,"traceId":"|a8a2c5a-4e9cfc5e41a08a61.","errors":{"$":["The input does not contain any JSON tokens. Expected the input to start with a valid JSON token, when isFinalBlock is true. Path: $ | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 0."],"setGlobally":["The value 'authenticate' is not valid."],"providerType":["The value 'avatar' is not valid."]}}

setGlobally and providerType are optional params for the authenticate method.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Authenticate and log in using the given avatar credentials. Pass in the provider you wish to use. Set the setglobally flag to false for this provider to be used only for this request or true for it to be used for all future requests too.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="model"></param>
    /// <param name="providerType"></param>
    /// <param name="setGlobally"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    [HttpPost("authenticate/{providerType}/{setGlobally}")]
    public ActionResult<AuthenticateResponse> Authenticate(AuthenticateRequest model, ProviderType providerType = ProviderType.Default, bool setGlobally = false)
    {
        GetAndActivateProvider(providerType, setGlobally);
        return Authenticate(model);

        AuthenticateResponse response = _avatarService.Authenticate(model, ipAddress());

        if (!response.IsError && response.Avatar != null)
            setTokenCookie(response.Avatar.RefreshToken);

        return Ok(response);
    }

    
    /// <summary>
    /// Authenticate and log in using the given avatar credentials.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="model"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    [HttpPost("authenticate")]
    public ActionResult<AuthenticateResponse> Authenticate(AuthenticateRequest model)
    {
        AuthenticateResponse response = _avatarService.Authenticate(model, ipAddress());

        if (!response.IsError && response.Avatar != null)
            setTokenCookie(response.Avatar.RefreshToken);

        return Ok(response);
    }
```

Full code here:

https://github.com/NextGenSoftwareUK/Our-World-OASIS-API-HoloNET-HoloUnity-And-.NET-HDK/blob/master/NextGenSoftware.OASIS.API.ONODE.WebAPI/Controllers/AvatarController.cs

NOTE: IT LOOKS LIKE THIS IS ALSO AN ISSUE FOR ALL METHODS ON THE WEB API SO SOMETHING DEFINTLEY GOING ON WITH THE DEPLOYMENT? It works locally fine so I can't work out what is going on?

This may also be related to another issue that started occurring out of the blue after no code had been changed:

https://github.com/NextGenSoftwareUK/Our-World-OASIS-API-HoloNET-HoloUnity-And-.NET-HDK/issues/15

Any help would be really appreciated thanks. :)